# How to make TypeScript recognise conditional type inside if statements

Tags: typescript

We have a conditional event type that type hints different payloads depending on the event type:

```js
type EventType = 'created' | 'updated' | 'deleted'
type EventPayload<T> =
  T extends 'created' ? { somethingForCreatedEvent: string } :
  T extends 'updated' ? { somethingForUpdatedEvent: stirng } :
  T extends 'deleted' ? { somethingForDeletedEvent: string } :
  never
```

This allows us to get strong typing with an event `trigger` function:

```js
function trigger<T extends EventType>(type: T, payload: EventPayload<T>) {
  // send the event off
}

trigger('created', { /* correctly type hints "somethingForCreatedEvent" as the only property */ })
trigger('updated', { /* correctly type hints "somethingForUpdatedEvent" as the only property */ })
trigger('deleted', { /* correctly type hints "somethingForDeletedEvent" as the only property */ })
```

The issue we are facing is getting strong typing on the receiving of the event. It's in a different part of the system, but uses the same types via our internal SDK:

```js
// We receive event payload from a queue in the format of
// { type: EventType; payload: EventPayload<...> }
const eventPayload = req.body // has a type of "any" at this point

if (eventPayload.type === 'created') {
  eventPayload.payload // any/unknown type
}
```

How do we let TypeScript know what this type is based on the `if` statement? We cannot cast it to the `EventPayload<T>` type since `T` must be inferred from the "type" - which, as far as I know, cannot be done since we only know the "type" at runtime.

We have tried making a helper function to hint the type, but it does not work as expected:

```js
type RawEvent<T> = {
  type: T;
  payload: EventPayload<T>;
}

function getEventPayload<T extends EventType>(rawEvent: any): RawEvent<T> {
  return rawEvent
}

const event = getEventPayload(rawEvent)

if (event.type === 'created') { // <- correctly hints "created" as a type
  event.payload // type is a union of all EventPayload types, instead of just "created" type
}
```

Comment: How do we get from a payload `{ somethingForCreatedEvent: string }` to the whole event `{ event: EventType; payload: EventPayload<T> }`? How do you get to the latter type?

Comment: @kelly From the `trigger` function we would post the event as `{ event: EventType; payload: EventPayload<T> }`. The reason being is that we must receive the type and the payload via a POST request body later on.

Comment: So the body would be something like `return { event, payload };`?

Comment: @kelly That's correct yes

Comment: [Create a union of possible event objects](https://tsplay.dev/w8LBpw). Also changed your EventPayload type to use a map instead of chaining conditionals for performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type guards.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

```
const type CreatedType = { somethingForCreatedEvent: string };
const isCreatedType = (event): is CreatedType => {
  return event.type === 'created'
}

if(isCreatedType(event)) {
  console.log(event.somethingForCreatedEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Taking Simon's answer one step further, we were able to abstract the "type guard" solution to be generic to the use case:

```js
type EventType = 'created' | 'updated' | 'deleted'

type EventPayload<T> =
  T extends 'created' ? { somethingForCreatedEvent: string } :
  T extends 'updated' ? { somethingForUpdatedEvent: stirng } :
  T extends 'deleted' ? { somethingForDeletedEvent: string } :
  never

type RawEvent<T> = {
  type: T;
  payload: EventPayload<T>;
}

function isEventType<T extends EventType>(rawEvent: RawEvent<T>, eventType: T): rawEvent is RawEvent<T> {
  return rawEvent.type === eventType
}

const rawEvent: any = getTheEvent()

if (isEventType(rawEvent, 'created')) {
  rawEvent.payload.somethingForCreated // <- Correctly strongly typed
}
```